# while parsing email content why class and id attributes are removed

Tags: email

In many of the web email clients while parsing email content , they remove class and id attributes from the email content. why they are removing so? If those things are retained what are the problems may occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do it for security reasons.  It might be an overly aggressive filter, but a lot of people are paranoid like that.

Microsoft Outlook for example doesn't allow any CSS or even inline CSS.  Most clients will block external scripts/images, this is so that the email author cannot tell if the email was opened or not.  EG:

```
<img src="http://spamsite.com/img1.jpg?uniqueCode=3543407" />
```

The server links the unique code to that email dispatch, and then you know if the address is a valid one when the image is requested, opening the floodgates to more spam, because hey, this guy opens and reads these emails.

I imagine blocking classes/ID's is associated with blocking external CSS/Javascript from running.  Also internal CSS with background images loaded from external URLs can be a security concern, so I imagine the email clients just decided to block it all instead of writing complicated and hard to maintain rules to filter out all the dangerous bits.